# Do I need to re-send the same GRE test score if I want to apply for the same graduate program again?

Tags: gre

I applied for a master program of university X two years ago and was rejected. Then I went to another master program and now I am about to finish. I want to apply for the PhD program of university X this year, and I have no plan to re-take the GRE test. I am wondering if it is need to re-send the GRE score to the same department of the same university.

Comment: If the score is recent, you won't need to retake the GRE. Ask the program if they need another official report.

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. You are going to have to ask them what they need. they may even want you to retake the test.

Comment: You'll have to ask university X, they are the ultimate and only authority when it comes to the exact application rules of university X. It would be a bad idea to base such decisions on the advise of some random people in the internet.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the university. Many of them don't retain materials from applicants whom they ultimately did not accept. However, their policies regarding GRE scores may differ.

Shoot an email to the department; they should reply within a few days.